# How to import blueprints with the same name as the file they are in?

Tags: python, flask, python-import

### Background

I'm trying to set up a blueprint whose name matches the filename it resides in, so that when I reference it in my `app.py` I know where the blueprint comes from. This should be possible because the example on [exploreflask](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html#basic-usage) uses the same pattern. Still, I cannot figure out how to make this work with my structure.

### File structure

```
├── app.py
├── frontend
    ├── __init__.py
    └── views
        ├── home.py
        └── __init__.py
```

### Example

**frontend/views/home.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

home = Blueprint('home', __name__)
home1 = Blueprint('home1', __name__)
```

**frontend/views/__init__.py**

```
from .home import home
from .home import home1
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

from frontend.views import home
from frontend.views import home1

print (type(home))  --> <class 'function'> 
print (type(home1)) --> <class 'flask.blueprints.Blueprint'>
```

As `home1` registers correctly as a `Blueprint` but `home` does not I suspect that
there is a name collision but I don't know how to resolve it despite looking into
[this excellent article](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-init-for-me-d70a312da583) on importing conventions.

As a result, when I try to register my blueprints with the app
 this will work:

```
app.register_blueprint(home1, url_prefix='/home1') --> Fine
```

but this won't:

```
app.register_blueprint(home, url_prefix='/home')
--> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
```

### Why not just go along with using home1?

1. I want to understand how the collision can be resolved
2. I want to be able to use route names that are the same as the filename they are in like so:

**frontend/views/home.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

home = Blueprint('home', __name__)

@home.route('/')
def home():
  pass
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the Divisional or Functional structure described in [exporeflask](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html#basic-usage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your views/__init__.py file is causing this issue. It's making python assume your `home.py` file is a module to be imported. I believe the line `from frontend.views import home` is trying to import the `home.py` file rather than your intended `home.home` Blueprint.

Here's a working example:

/app.py

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

/app/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__) 
    from .bp import bp  
    app.register_blueprint(bp)   
    return app
```

/app/bp/__init__.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__, template_folder='templates')
from . import views
```

/app/bp/views.py

```
from app.bp import bp

@bp.route('/helloworld')
def helloworld():

    return "hello world"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Capital letters in the Blueprint Module.

also you can use the url_prefix in the module.

```
Home = Blueprint("Home", __name__, url_prefix="/home")

@Home.route("/")
def home():
    pass
```

Comment: Using capital letters could be a hacky workaround, but that's exactly what I'd like to avoid. Besides it violates PEP8: capitals are for classes. The `url_prefix` is unrelated to the problem (and I'm using it already, anyway).